# retrieve values ​from an html file

Tags: r, shiny

I am learning to program with shiny but I am stuck on some actions.

I have a html file (index.html, which also contains css code) where you need to enter a username and password and a login button which is used to send the values ​​of the username and password fields.

I would like to know how to retrieve username and password values ​​when we click on login in app.R file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Login Form</h2>

<form >
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="https://www.cote-azur-ecobiz.fr/upload/docs/image/jpeg/2015-03/exemple.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

**app.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = htmlTemplate("www/index.html"), server)
```

Comment: You need to modify your template such that you can work with shiny elements. The shiny template page gives more details: [shiny templates](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html)

Comment: hello, thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve `user` and `password` you can access `input$uname` and `input$psw`. This is the name that appear in your HTML file. To observe the submit button I recommend you to use an `action-button` instead of a `submit` one (see for example `?shiny::submitButton)`.

Here is the HTML file in which I changed the button type and added the id parameter as *submit_btn*:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Login Form</h2>

<form >
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="https://www.cote-azur-ecobiz.fr/upload/docs/image/jpeg/2015-03/exemple.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button id="submit_btn" class="action-button">Login</button>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
```

Here is an app just to check the results:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  login <- eventReactive(input$submit_btn,{
    user <- input$uname
    password <- input$psw

    return(c("user" = user, "password" = password))
  })

  output$login_out <- renderText({
    login_data <- login()
    sprintf("User: %s; Password: %s", login_data[1], login_data[2])
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    includeHTML("www/index.html"),
    textOutput("login_out")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server)
```